# Any python Framework for Testing with Reporting capability

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to work with selenium webdriver with python bindings (worked with java before). Just want to check if there is any testing framework like "TestNG" available in Python which is having reporting capabilities (like TestNG). Came across framework like "Nose", "unittest" and i am not sure it will generate test report.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nose has an [`xunit` plugin](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/xunit.html#module-nose.plugins.xunit) that allows to output test results into `XUnit XML format`. Then, you can feed the report to a `CI`, like `Jenkins`.

Run your tests with `--with-xunit` option:

```
nosetests --with-xunit
```

And see the results in `nosetests.xml`. You can also control the report file location by using `--xunit-file` option.

Also, there is a module called [`proboscis`](https://github.com/rackerlabs/python-proboscis) that brings `TestNG` features to Python.